# Replacing IDs in two columns using another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

ID_Equiv:

```
PDA_ZoneID Distribution_ZoneID
101         1
102         2
103         3
104         4
105         5
```

Distribution_byDistribID:

```
Origin Destination Distribution
1701    1           0.1
1701    2           0.2
1701    3           0.3
1701    4           0.4
1701    5           0.1
1      1701         0.1
2      1701         0.2
3      1701         0.3
4      1701         0.4
5      1701         0.1
1704    1           0.1
1704    2           0.2
1704    3           0.3
1704    4           0.4
1704    5           0.1
1      1704         0.1
2      1704         0.2
3      1704         0.3
4      1704         0.4
5      1704         0.1
```

I would like to use the ID_Equiv table to replace the IDs in the `Distribution_byDistribID` table to use the `PDA_ZoneID` instead of `Distribution_ZoneID` and give the following:

```
Origin Destination Distribution
1701    101         0.1
1701    102         0.2
1701    103         0.3
1701    104         0.4
1701    105         0.1
101    1701         0.1
102    1701         0.2
103    1701         0.3
104    1701         0.4
105    1701         0.1
1704    101         0.1
1704    102         0.2
1704    103         0.3
1704    104         0.4
1704    105         0.1
101    1704         0.1
102    1704         0.2
103    1704         0.3
104    1704         0.4
105    1704         0.1
```

I have tried a combination of joins and also union, but nothing seemed to give me what I needed.

Thank you!

Comment: please attach your query what u have tried so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: you can use `LEFT JOIN` to achieve the desired output. We can do separate join for both the columns with the `ID_Equiv` to retrieve the desired value to update the columns `Destination` and `Origin`

```
UPDATE dd SET 
    dd.Destination = ISNULL(ie.PDA_ZoneID, dd.Destination), 
    dd.Origin = ISNULL(ie1.PDA_ZoneID, dd.Origin)
FROM Distribution_byDistribID dd
LEFT JOIN ID_Equiv ie ON dd.Destination = ie.Distribution_ZoneID
LEFT JOIN ID_Equiv ie1 ON dd.Origin = ie1.Distribution_ZoneID
```

If you want just it to select then:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(ie1.PDA_ZoneID, dd.Origin) AS Origin, 
    ISNULL(ie.PDA_ZoneID, dd.Destination) AS Destination, 
    dd.Distribution
FROM Distribution_byDistribID dd
LEFT JOIN ID_Equiv ie ON dd.Destination = ie.Distribution_ZoneID
LEFT JOIN ID_Equiv ie1 ON dd.Origin = ie1.Distribution_ZoneID
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed! I have used the select version and created a view to keep the table. Thanks @Susang!